# Sql to Select record by latest date and decided by that

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I didn't know what to write for title 
I have table like this:

```
RegistrationNumber- Class- Score- Session Date - Session Time
2000905         | Class1  | 80    |2014-07-13|  10:00-13:00 
2000019         | Class1  | 70    |2014-07-19|  15:00-18:00
2000007         | Class1  | 70    |2014-07-18|  10:00-13:00 
2000007         | Class1  | 70    |2014-07-14|  15:00-18:00 
2000007         | Class1  | 70    |2014-07-11|  10:00-13:00 
2000907         | Class2  | Null  |2014-07-12|  15:00-18:00
2000006         | Class2  | 34    |2014-07-13|  10:00-13:00 
2005612         | Class2  | 55    |2014-07-14|  15:00-18:00 
2000919         | Class2  | 65    |2014-07-15|  11:00-12:00 
2001034         | Class2  | 29    |2014-07-14|  11:00-12:00 
2000000         | Class2  | 45    |2014-07-14|  11:00-12:00 
2000000         | Class2  | 45    |2014-07-14|  15:00-18:00 
2000000         | Class2  | 45    |2014-07-15|  10:00-13:00
2001029         | Class2  | Null  |2014-07-17|  10:00-13:00
```

I want to write a SQL which brings datas as shown below
The idea is sorting by RegistrationNumber, Class,SessionDate,SessionTime  and then whoever has score 
and one session then but Y(Yes ) for Attendance . If the same person has more than 1 session for
the same class then it should put Y only for the lastest session and the previous ones should be No

```
RegistrationNumber- Class- Score- Session Date - Session Time -Attendance   

2000000         | Class2  | 45    |2014-07-14|  11:00-12:00 |   N           
2000000         | Class2  | 45    |2014-07-14|  15:00-18:00 |   N           
2000000         | Class2  | 45    |2014-07-15|  10:00-13:00 |   Y           
2000007         | Class1  | 70    |2014-07-11|  10:00-13:00 |   N           
2000007         | Class1  | 70    |2014-07-14|  15:00-18:00 |   N           
2000007         | Class1  | 70    |2014-07-18|  10:00-13:00 |   Y           
2000006         | Class2  | 34    |2014-07-13|  10:00-13:00 |   Y           
2000019         | Class1  | 70    |2014-07-19|  15:00-18:00 |   Y           
2000905         | Class1  | 80    |2014-07-13|  10:00-13:00 |   Y           
2000907         | Class2  | Null  |2014-07-12|  15:00-18:00 |   N          
2000919         | Class2  | 65    |2014-07-15|  11:00-12:00 |   Y           
2001029         | Class2  | Null  |2014-07-17|  10:00-13:00 |   N          
2001034         | Class2  | 29    |2014-07-14|  11:00-12:00 |   Y           
2005612         | Class2  | 55    |2014-07-14|  15:00-18:00 |   Y
```

Comment: What identifies the different "Persons"?

Comment: RegistrationNumber. Every person has different Registration Number

Comment: You store a score per session. What if the last session for a registration number and class has no score, but the second last one has? Will all those sessions get an 'N' then or will the second last get a 'Y'?

Comment: If reg number for one course  has score it will have for all  sessions of the same course. Sorry, I didn't understand the second part of your question. If one registration number has several sessions and the Score >0 then only the last one will be Y , the others No.

Comment: Okay. But the sessions for one class can have different scores I hope. Otherwise your data model would not be normalized holding redundant values and could thus lead to data inconsistency and related problems one day. You should change it then.

Comment: I just see you talked of existing scores before and now it's scores > 0. Does NULL and zero mean the same for you here? I thought NULL means something like not rated yet whereas 0 means a person scored 0. No? Do both mean "not attended"? Then you should make this column non-nullable, so there are no longer two values representing the same thing.

Comment: For the same scores every registration number have one score. it is my temporary table ( select result). Here the scores are Null . It means they didn't attend the course. if the score isn't null or >0 it means  he/she didn't attend  the course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea.  Get the information you want using window functions.  Then just use these in a `case` statement.  I think the logic is:

```
select RegistrationNumber, Class, Score, SessionDate, SessionTime,
       (case when score is not null and cnt = 1 then 'Y'
             when cnt > 1 and seqnum = cnt then 'Y'
             else 'N'
        end) as Attendance
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by RegistrationNumber, Class
                                order by SessionDate, SessionTime) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by RegistrationNumber, Class) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
order by RegistrationNumber, Class, SessionDate, SessionTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to show an alternative to Gordon's answer: You want the *last* record per registrationnumber and class and make it a 'Y' (provided it has a score). So this is the *first* in *reverse* order. Use row_number with the reverse order hence to determine this first or rather last record :-)

```
select
  registrationnumber, class, score, session_date, session_time,
  case when score > 0 and row_number() over (
                           partition by registrationnumber, class 
                           order by session_date desc, session_time desc) = 1 then
    'Y'
  else
    'N'
  end as attendance 
from mytable
order by registrationnumber, class, session_date, session_time;
```

Comment: nice way of thinking. this one is shorter and works faster . one less select. great. thanks